# Error: Failed to create Data Storage while running embedded pig in java

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I wrote a simple program to test the embedded pig in java to run in mapreduce mode.
The hadoop version in the server I am running is 0.20.2-cdh3u4a, and pig version is 0.10.0-cdh3u4a.

When I try to run in local mode, it runs successfully. But when I try to run in mapreduce mode, it gives me the error.

I run my program using the following commands as shown in http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/cont.html#embed-java

```
javac -cp pig.jar EmbedPigTest.java
javac -cp pig.jar:.:/etc/hadoop/conf EmbedPigTest.java input.txt
```

My program gives error as:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create DataStorage
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.datastorage.HDataStorage.init(HDataStorage.java:75)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.datastorage.HDataStorage.<init>(HDataStorage.java:58)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.init(HExecutionEngine.java:214)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.init(HExecutionEngine.java:134)
        at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.connect(PigContext.java:183)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.<init>(PigServer.java:226)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.<init>(PigServer.java:215)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.<init>(PigServer.java:211)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.<init>(PigServer.java:207)
        at WordCount.main(EmbedPigTest.java:9)
```

In some online resources they say that this problem occurs due to different hadoop version. But, I didn't understand what I should do. Suggestions please !!

Comment: My /etc/hadoo/conf location contains these files: core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml, mapred-site.xml, but not **hadoop-site.xml**. Do I need to give the path to hadoop-site.xml or this will mork?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are linking to the wrong jar, Please see the link below it describes this issue very well.

http://localsteve.wordpress.com/2012/09/30/embedding-pig-for-cdh4-java-apps-fer-realz/

Answer (score 0):

I was faced same kind of issue when I tried to use pig in map reduce mode without starting the services.

Please check all services using jps before using pig in map reduce mode.